# Cross Domain references to parent host preserved

Tags: php, url, iframe, cross-domain

There exists a page on a remote url that can be accessed with a login that is posted using a query string. `http://www.example.com/exampleURI?user=user&pass=pass`. Lets call this URL location the `parent url` from here on.

I do not have access to the that url (ie. it is not on my server). I created a login form on my server (not the server of the `parent url` I mentioned above) that makes a POST to my php file which does a `file_get_contents` request to the above url. If login credentials are correct then it sends back the entire body of a page.

There is lots of stuff going on ajax wise on that page that was returned to me. A lot of the processes require that they are being hosted on the `parent URL`. It also has refrences to images that only exist in the `parent url`. I want to be able to house an iframe of that page on my page, on my server, but retain the iframes refrence to its `parent url` for reasons just mentioned.

I need to make cross window manipulation of the dom inside the iframe. The same origin policy of most browsers prohibit me from accomplishing this. **Is there a way to, for example, attach event listeners to dom elements within the iframe?**

How is something like this accomplished if at all?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you don't want to expose the parent url to your end users?

Comment: The parent url may be exposed without any issues.

Comment: Then why not just load the parent url as the src of the iframe, prefilled with the login credentials?

Comment: you're right, and thats what I'm doing. But I also need to make cross window manipulation of the dom inside the iframe. I didn't include that in my question as a mistake, I'll edit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll proof to be very difficult - if not impossible (if you can't change anything on the parent's server). This is by the way a good thing, as it would make spoofing a whole lot easier.

Comment: i think i might have found something. Does this seem feasible http://softwareas.com/injecting-html-into-an-iframe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19431/discussion-between-hongaar-and-sofianem)

Answer (score 0):

You want to try [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) requests which are cross domain. Unfortunately the response has to be adequate and especially prepared for you, so this works if you control both domains. Most libraries know today how to do this kind of request.

Also take a look at [Comet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-reverseajax1/index.html).